# Latex - skip numbering in an enumerate environment

Tags: latex, enumerate

I would like to skip numbering in a Latex enumerate environment to generate lists as follows:

(1) Item 1..

(2) Item 2..

(5) Item 5..

(6) Item 6..

and so on.

The Latex code is auto-generated, so *ideally*, I would like to insert "silent" \item-s in the environment, so that they will keep track of the numbering but nothing will appear on the output. However, if I simply add empty \items currently, I get lists like the following:

(1) Item 1

(2) Item 2

(3)

(4)

(5) Item 5

(6) Item 6

While the empty \item-s approach is the most ideal, I'm more than welcome to any other ways of achieving the number-skipping.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depending on the level of enumeration, a simple `\setcounter{enumi}{5}` would suffice. (the number of `i`'s after the `enum` in the first argument is the level of enumeration.

Another approach would be to call `\stepcounter{enumi}` as many times as you want to skip items. This makes the number of skipped items independent of the number of items before you skip.
EDIT: the last option is the most like inserting "silent `item`'s".

EDIT: its probably best *not* to hack LaTeX, but use the `list` environment (see the LaTeX documentation on how to use this). Since your LaTeX code is auto-generated, it should not be hard to generate the labels, and put them in a list environment.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `\addtocounter{enumi}{2}` (for example, in your particular case) to skip 2 items.